# Link to a tabpanel within navbarMenu from another tabpanel outside navbarMenu in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, hyperlink, tabs

I  hope the title is self explanatory. I saw  similar questions answered with JavaScript, but it would be great if it could be done with R. Here is a minimal example of what i tried and did not work (also tried updateNavbarPage()). I am trying to set a link in tabpanel B to go from tabpanel B to tabpanel D.

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage(
    "A",
    tabPanel("A1",
             sidebarPanel(),
             mainPanel(
               tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                           id = "panels",
                           # Tabsets  in mainPanel----     
                           tabPanel("B",
                                    hr(),
                                    HTML("This is panel B <br>"),
                                    hr(),
                                    actionLink("link_to_D", "Go to D")
                                    ), # Tabpanel
                           tabPanel("C",
                                    hr(),
                                    HTML("This is panel C"))   
                           )# tabsetPanel
             )# mainPanel
    ),#tabPanel
    
    navbarMenu("About",
               tabPanel("D",
                        hr(),
                        HTML("This is panel D")),
               tabPanel("E" ,
                        hr(),
                        HTML("This is panel E"))
    ) #NavbarMenu
  ) # NavbarPage  
  
) # fluidPage

  
# Define server 
server <- function(input, output,session) {
   
    # Link to D
  observeEvent(input$link_to_D, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "C", "D")
  })


  
}  # server  


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Could you indicate any packages needed to run this code or remove these pieces of code if they are not essential to the question?

Comment: Removed `shinythemes("sandstone)`, added `library(shiny)`, and added some text to each panel to known in which panel the user is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. The issue is only that in SHiny you do not update the tab panel directly. Instead you update the "mother" element which is either a `tabSetPanel` or - in your case - the `navbarPage`. So you need to give the `navbarPage` an id and call `updateNavbarPage`.

Example:

```r
library(shiny)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage(
    "A-Title",
    tabPanel("A1",
             sidebarPanel(),
             mainPanel(
               tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                           id = "panels",
                           # Tabsets  in mainPanel----
                           tabPanel("B",
                                    hr(),
                                    actionLink("link_to_D", "Go to D")
                           ), # Tabpanel
                           tabPanel("C")
               )# tabsetPanel
             )# mainPanel
    ),#tabPanel

    navbarMenu("About",
               tabPanel("D", "I am D"),
               tabPanel("E", "I am E")
    ), #NavbarMenu
    id="MainNavBar" # Step 1: Give the navbarPage an id
  ) # NavbarPage

) # fluidPage


# Define server
server <- function(input, output,session) {

  # Link to D
  observeEvent(input$link_to_D, {
    #--updateTabsetPanel(session, "C", "D")
    # update selected tab to "D"
    updateNavbarPage(inputId="MainNavBar", selected = "D")
  })



}  # server


# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Great thanks! when do i have to include `session` on `updateNavbarPage`? I am not able to understand the documentation on this.

Comment: I can say that I have never used the `session` argument, so far.